# Django + DRF: 403 FORBIDDEN: CSRF token missing or incorrect

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, csrf, django-allauth, django-rest-auth

I have an Android client app that tries to authenticate with a Django + DRF backend. However, when I try to login, I get the following response:

```
403: CSRF Failed: CSRF token missing or incorrect.
```

The request is sent to `http://localhost/rest-auth/google/` with the following body:

```
access_token: <the OAuth token from Google>
```

What could cause this? The client doesn't have a CSRF token since the POST to authenticate is the first thing to happen between the client and the server. I checked out a lot of the past questions with the same problem, but I couldn't find any solutions.

The relevant settings on the Django side are like this:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend"
)

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    "django.core.context_processors.request",
    "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount"
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
)

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'app',
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.facebook',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',

    'django.contrib.admin',

    # REST framework
    'rest_framework',
    'rest_framework.authtoken',
    'rest_auth',
    'rest_auth.registration',
)

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': ( 
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated'
    ),
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Silly me, I missed the `TokenAuthentication` framework from the REST settings:

**settings.py**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication',
    )
}
```

Now it works just as intended.

Answer (score 12):

**Why are you getting this error?**

As you have not defined the `AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in your settings, DRF uses the following default authentication classes.

```
'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
    'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
    'rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication'
)
```

Now, [`SessionAuthentication`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/authentication/#sessionauthentication) enforces the use of `CSRF Token`. If you don't pass a valid CSRF token, then 403 error is raised.

> If you're using an AJAX style API with `SessionAuthentication`, you'll
>   need to make sure you include a valid CSRF token for any "unsafe" HTTP
>   method calls, such as`PUT`, `PATCH`, `POST` or `DELETE` requests.

**What you need to do then?**

Since you are using `TokenAuthentication`, you need to explicitly define it in the `AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES` in your DRF settings. This should resolve your CSRF token issue.

Comment: You say we have to pass a valid CSRF token. Where do I find this token? In my case the problem come when I try to login with `rest-auth/login/` endpoint. But it's the first contact between the client and the server, so the client desn't know the token.

Comment: Check this Django docs [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/csrf/#ajax) to get CSRF Token for Ajax requests.

Comment: Thank you @rahul-gupta but I'm not on a web environment. I'm on a c# environment (Xamarin). But in any case, in a rest<>client application, the client can not know the csrf if the server has not told it to him.

Comment: Then you should use a different authentication class as `SessionAuthentication` requires a CSRF token to be sent. You will need to explicitly define that particular authentication class in your settings or your particular view.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the csrf token while sending the request lets see the given code:

```
function getCookie(name) {
 var cookieValue = null;
 if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
     var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
     for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
         var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
         // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
         if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
             cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
             break;
         }
     }
 }
 return cookieValue;
}

const check = () => {

 const endPoint = '/api/check/'
 const csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken'); // getting the cookie to pass as csrf token

 return fetch(baseUrl + endPoint,{
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'X-CSRFToken': csrftoken
        },
        
    })
    .then(response => {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response
        }
        else { 
            if (response.status === 401 && response.statusText === 'Unauthorized'){ // if it is un authorized then dispatch the logout
                dispatch(logout());
            }
            var error = new Error('Error: '+ response.status + ': ' + response.statusText); 
            error.response = response;  
            throw error; 
        }

    },               
    error => {
        var errmess = new Error(error.message); 
        throw errmess;
    })
    .then( data => data.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .catch(error => console.log(error.message)); 
   }
```

Guys one thing remember no matter you are sending the GET PUT or POST request you need to send the csrf token this is for the security purpose.

I hope my answer help you.

Answer (score 0):

This error can happen due to improper implementation of `urlpatterns` including static URL paths. To debug,

1. Check whether you have set authentication classes correctly.

   ```
   REST_FRAMEWORK = {
       'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
           <your auth classes>
       )
   }
   ```
2. Check whether the paths for the class-based views are properly defined.

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       '<your URL path>', <your class-based view>.as_view(), name='<path name>')
   ]
   ```
3. Check whether you have defined `urlpatterns` for static and media files and also have defined them correctly in `setting.py`.

   In `settings.py`:

   ```
   STATIC_URL = '/static/'
   STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
   # STATIC_ROOT = '/assets'

   STATICFILES_DIRS = [
       os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
   ]

   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
   ```

   In `urls.py`:

   ```
   urlpatterns = [
       ...
   ]
   urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
   urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
   ```